# append to array causing crash

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append, crashlytics

I have the following crash report for this piece of code. I'm unsure why this is wrong.

Crash:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libswiftCore.dylib                 0x1082ebf94 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 106516
1  libswiftCore.dylib                 0x10818c214 default argument 0 of _preconditionFailure(_:file:line:) + 109688
2  libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib    0x108804d60 specialized _ArrayBufferProtocol._arrayOutOfPlaceUpdate<A>(_:_:_:_:) + 55124
3  libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib    0x1087f9178 specialized Array._copyToNewBuffer(oldCount:) + 7020
4  libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib    0x1087f51bc specialized Array.append(_:) + 17480
```

Code:

```
self.missingEmployees.removeAll()
for eid in eids {
    let indexFound = self.employees.index(where: {$0.employeeId == eid})
    if indexFound == nil {
        self.missingEmployees.append(eid)
    }
}
```

Would a guard let approach in the for loop get rid of this issue?

Comment: What holds you from trying that?

Comment: @Desdenova nothing but I cannot reproduce the crash so I am asking to see if anyone has knowledge on why the above would crash, because I don't see what is wrong with it and a guard let might just lead to the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I just received this error myself. For me this was caused by modifying the array from different threads. Arrays are not thread-safe.

I solved this using GCD and put the append operation in a sync block. On another place I solved it using NSCache, because NSCache is thread-safe already.

Comment: Totally agree with you.

Comment: @haagneti I'm faing the same crash and  i used serial queue though getting crash.
``let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SerialQueue")               //Multiple threads modifying array at same time so putin queue
                        serialQueue.sync {
                            self.result.append(ContactModel(contactName: personName, mobileNo: arrPhoneNumber, contactType: arrContactType, profileImage: userProfileImage, digitPhoneNumber: arrPhoneNumberWithOnlyNumber, countryRegionCode: arrTerritoryCode, contactUniqueIdentifier: personIdentifier))
                        }```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find difference between arrays in swift, there are several ways to do that.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set

You can go either with `subtract` or create a new set via `formSymmetricDifference`.

Comment: Kruhowski I just need to append to an array based on a certain condition

Comment: Still the best way to do it to use Set Algebra and do proper comparation methods on your custom object - I assume Employee. At least in my opinion

Comment: Can you understand why the index where actually caused a crash? How might you modify the small for loop to use your suggestions?